# Windows Forms - split comboBox in two

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I try to recreate Accept-made user interface with .NET/VisualStudio2010 utilities. In one of the forms I saw this:

[image]

you can see how the info is separated as it's taken from two different tables. Is it possible to achieve the same thing with Windows Form and if so - how can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could have sworn that I've done that in the past but now I'm wondering if that was back in my vb6 days with some other control because all signs point to no now that I'm trying to figure it out.

I did, however, find something that might be useful for you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19781/A-data-bound-multi-column-combobox